# R Studio - Error in function_list[[i]](value) : no se pudo encontrar la función "rename_all"

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar una linea de código en R Studio.

```
com00 <- com_2016 %>%
   rename_all( str_replace_all, " " , "_" )
```

> Error in function_list[k] :    no se pudo encontrar la
>   función "rename_all"

Ya tengo instalada la libreria tidyverse, aún así, no me reconoce la función "rename_all".

Támpoco al poner

```
?rename_all
```

> No documentation for ‘rename_all’ in specified packages and libraries:
>   you could try ‘??rename_all’

Utilizo R versión 3.6.1
R Studio 1.2.5019

Gracias.

Comment: Has importado `dplyr`? con `library("dplyr")`

Comment: Me corrijo, si ni siquiera tienes la ayuda, no tienes `dplyr` instalada, o si, pero con alguna versión antigua que no tenga esta función. Prueba con `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: Patricio Moracho, muchas gracias, por tu comentario. respondiendo a tu comentario, ya instalé las librerias tidyverse, stringr, ggedit, lubridate y dplyr.

Comment: Prueba invocar la función anteponiendo el nombre del paquete `dplyr::rename_all()` a ver que ocurre

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tampoco funciona, creo que hay un problema con la versión 3.6.1 de R, o simplemente en dicha versión cambiaron la función. saludos¡

Comment: No, te confirmo que con la versión 3.6.1 funciona perfecto, en todo caso fue un problema en la instalación del paquete. Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue utilizar la versión de R 3.5.3, aparentemente la versión 3.6.1 no reconoce rename_all(), alguien sabe la razón?

saludos¡